# Does Mathematica Integrate Hypergeometric Functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am doing some work where the Hypergeometric functions keep on appearing. I have an older version of Mathematica - 9.0.1.0 MS Windows 64-bit.

Do later versions of Mathematica integrate Hypergeometric functions?

Here is an example...

```
Integrate[(EX2 Subscript[λ, R])/(
2 (1 + (n α (θ/
   T)^-α (θ^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 
      1 + n - 2/α, 
      2 - 2/α, (θ/T)^-α] - 
    x^2 (θ/
      x)^α (((θ/T)^α - (θ/
        x)^α)/(-1 + (θ/T)^α))^
     n Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + n - 2/α, 
      2 - 2/α, (θ/T)^-α (θ/
        x)^α]) Subscript[λ, R])/(
    x (-2 + α)))) (1 - (-1 + (θ/
   t)^α)/(-1 + (θ/T)^α))^(-1 + 
   n), {x, θ, T}]
```

Comment: You have lots of stuff in the integral that does not depend on `x`. You should first manually reduce the complexity of the integrand and the number of variables to the minimum possible. And then you need to use assumptions for all remaining parameters since the integral most likely does not converge for arbitrary complex values of the parameters. Even then it might not work, but in the way you write it even much simpler integrals would not give a result.

Comment: I tried that in 11.0. Mma could not do it. I think Felix has given very good advice +1